# Interrogating an NSArray that appears to have a null entry

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPad app that links to an SQL database to retrieve information in the following way:

```
NSString *strGetCodeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://website/getdevicecode.php?device=" , deviceName];
NSArray *deviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strGetCodeUrl]];
```

This works when there is a device that matches and it retrieves the required information. However if there is not a match it returns

("")

The array however appears to have one record. Ideally I would like to stop this from happening and for the array to be empty if there is no match. Alternatively (although not very tidy) I could check the length of the entry at index 0 but I am struggling with this method.

```
NSString *deviceCode = [deviceArray objectAtIndex:0];
if ( [deviceCode length] == 0)
{
device does not exist
}
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: So how exactly are you "struggling" with this? (also, don't abuse format strings. You don't need `%@%@`, just the URL string and one `%@`.)

Comment: Sorry - pasting typo. only one %@ needed. Edited

Comment: @RichardGriffiths - You pasted incorrectly. What H2CO3 meant was `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website/getdevicecode.php?device=%@" , deviceName];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
NSString *deviceCode = [deviceArray objectAtIndex:0];
if ([deviceCode isEqualToString:@""])
{
device does not exist
}
```

Comment: If the first method didn't work, this won't work either. (but I dont see why any of them wouldn't work...)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can tell the init method to leave out empty strings...

However, you can do this:

```
NSString *strGetCodeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://website/getdevicecode.php?device=" , deviceName];
NSArray *deviceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strGetCodeUrl]];
[deviceArray removeObject:@""];
```

Which also isn't as tidy as perhaps you were hoping for, but it will remove all empty strings. But at least its just 1 line of code as opposed to about 3 for the if

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject%3a):

> Removes all occurrences in the array of a given object.